# Passing function as argument in R

Tags: r, function, arguments

I am trying to pass a customisable function as argument in R in the following function:

```
moving_window_filter2 <- function(vec, deltan, FUN = "min") {
  spectrum <- vec
  n <- length(vec)
  for (i in 1:n) {
    nmin <- max(1, i - deltan/2)
    nmax <- min(n, i + deltan/2)
    spectrum[i] <- FUN(vec[nmin:nmax])
  }
  return(spectrum)
}
```

However, this code results in an error saying that `Error in FUN(vec[nmin:nmax]) : could not find function "FUN"`. What should I do?

Many thanks.

Comment: try `FUN=min` (no quotation marks)?  (it would be good to have a [mcve])

Comment: you could also use a switch function, which may have some advantages if you want to check that the arguments to function are correct. e.g. by adding `FUN <- switch(FUN, "min" = min)`

Comment: Add the line `FUN  <- match.fun(FUN)` at the top of the body.  That will allow functions to be passed as either character strings or as functions.

Comment: A note to @I_O (now-deleted answer): `get(s)` is a much safer/more robust way to get from a string to a function than `eval(parse(text=s))` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you are mixing passing the function by name and then trying to apply it as the actual function object.

Use `do.call`. It accepts either.

```
moving_window_filter2 <- function(vec, deltan, FUN = "min") {
  spectrum <- vec
  n <- length(vec)
  for (i in 1:n) {
    nmin <- max(1, i - deltan/2)
    nmax <- min(n, i + deltan/2)
    spectrum[i] <- do.call(FUN, list(vec[nmin:nmax]))
  }
  return(spectrum)
}
```